# How to get progress of an AJAX page load in WordPress?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, wordpress

I use a plugin on my WordPress blog called Advanced Ajax Page Loader which simply loads the next page or post through AJAX and then puts it in my specified div. What I want to do is show a progress bar (not just say "Loading..." and show some type of animated gif) somewhere on the page.

Is this even possible? Each time you load a new post or page through PHP, the file size will be different.

It looks like `XMLHttpRequest.onprogress` is a good place to start, but like I said I don't know if it's possible to calculate the file size before retrieving a page is complete.

Comment: Is this really such a long running process that you would even want to do this?

Comment: Our servers aren't the best. Sometimes it takes 2 seconds to get the page, sometimes it takes 10. I think our server gets overloaded easily. But yeah I'd like to show a progress bar.

Answer (score 0):

For the ajax progress bar, just add this script into theme header.

http://github.hubspot.com/pace/docs/welcome/

```
<head>
  <script src="/pace/pace.js"></script>
  <link href="/pace/themes/pace-theme-barber-shop.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
```

**Don't Forget to add CSS. It will not show until you add some style.**